# Can't resolve R file

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I call the R it says can'ts resolve R symbol  ,, how could I fix this ?

```
package com.mohammadmustafa.web_loginregister.RegisterActivity.loginandregistration;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.mohammadmustafa.web_loginregister.RegisterActivity.loginandregistration.helper.SessionManager;
import  com.mohammadmustafa.web_loginregister.RegisterActivity.loginandregistration.helper.SQLiteHandler;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

all the R here is in a red line :

```
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
```

Comment: I don't think R is imported based on your code.

Comment: No instance named R; no evidence of a class named R with those static methods.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project again that might help you out. Or if nothing works than you should probably start new project R file will automatically will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

R is generated by default in android as it contains reference of other variables
check if you added code in (res->layout).xml first save it
jump to java code and use find view by id
(try select project->right click->android tools->fix project properties)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the R file manually. Then clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably in error or a duplication in one of your xml layout files. R.java cannot be created in gen folder of your project if you have xml errors. Fix the errors then clean and your project. Every time I get an error for R, its because I have an error in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Just rebuild and it will work again: Build -> Rebuild Project